# .Find in VBA between Datasets on different Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Fellow fans of StackOverflow,

I'm trying to use .Find with VBA but keep getting a rather annoying error. To be precise, it's error 424, object required.

Trying to learn, but have been struggling with this error for over 24 hours now and just can't seem to find my fault. I've added also some screenshots below so you can see the data for yourself.

Explanation of screenshots: Screenshot1 is my first Dataset, in which i want Column H populated by Column F from Screenshot2, my common caller is found in Column D in the first Dataset and in Column B in the second Dataset.

Summary of my problem: Been having error 424, object required with data below. Please help me find what I'm doing wrong, since I want to learn from this and have been struggling with this error for over 24 hours now.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheets("16-Compliancy-Rebuild")
Set sht2 = Sheets("OpmerkingBackup")
Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long
Dim rng As Range
Table1 = sht.Range("D85:D750")
Table2 = sht2.Range("B3:B750")
Dept_Row = sht.Range("H85").Row
Dept_Clm = sht.Range("H85").Column
For Each cl In Table1
Set rng = Table2.Find(cl, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    sht.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value
End If
  Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl
End Sub
```

[image: First dataset where i want to populate Column H]

[image: Second Dataset where i want to take column F and populate Column H in first Dataset]

Comment: Try using Set when you assign Table1 and Table 2 (as you did for sht) as I guess they are range variables (don't seem to be declared).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `SJR` mentioned - you are not using Set for the Tables.
However, in general, try to write your code, writing `Option Explicit` on top - then you should be forced to declare all variables.

Thus, you would need something like this:

```
Dim Table2 as Range
Dim Table1 as Range
```

Then, once they are defined as ranges, the error would be more visible and would be `91`:

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub TestMe()        
    Dim Table1 As Range
    Table1 = Range("A1:A5")    
End Sub
```

Error 91 is fixed by adding `Set Table1 = Range("A1:A5")`

Comment: First, thank you for your help.
How would i go and tackle the error 91 I am getting now?

Comment: Nevermind, found out by perstistence and trial and error. Thank you for your help.